# Chain awk regex matches like grep

Tags: awk

I am trying to use awk to select/remove data based on cell entries in a CSV file.

How do I chain Awk commands to build up complex searches like I have done with `grep`? I plan to use Awk to select rows based on matching criteria in cells in multiple columns, not just the first column as in this example.

Test data

```
123,line1
123a,line2
abc,line3
G-123,line4
G-123a,line5
```

Separate Awk statements with intermediate files

```
awk '$1 !~ /^[[:digit:]]/ {print $0}' file.txt > output1.txt
awk '$1 !~ /^G-[[:digit:]]/ {print $0}'  output1.txt > output2.txt
mv output2.txt output.txt
cat output.txt
```

Chained or multi-line `grep` version (I think limited to first column only)

```
grep -v \
     -e "^[[:digit:]]" \
     -e "^G-[[:digit:]]" \
     file.txt > output.txt
cat output.txt
```

How can I rewrite the Awk command to avoid the intermediate files?

Comment: The `^` in the `grep` anchors the matches to beginning of line. As long as the match doesn't straddle a column separator, that _effectively_ limits the matches to the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, in awk there are boolean operators available (it's *better* than grep! :) )

```
awk '/match1/ || /match2/' file
awk '(/match1/ || /match2/ ) && /match3/' file
```

and so on ...

---

In your example you could use something like:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]/ || $1 ~ /G-[[:digit:]]/' input >> output
```

Note: This is just an example of how to use boolean operators. Also the regular expression itself could have been used here to express the alternative match:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^(G-)?[[:digit:]]/' input >> ouput
```

Comment: Regarding `\-` - you don't need to escape `-` in a regexp, it's already literal unless it's inside a bracket expression and then for portability to all awk versions you should place it as the first or last char to make it literal rather than escaping it. Regarding `{0,1}` - that means the same as just `?`.

Comment: Hey, yes and yes! Thank you!! I never knew if awk's regular expressions language interprets `-`, or supports `?`. I just knew it will do _more than posix regular expressions and less than perl_ :) ... Will go though the manual

Comment: Awk just uses POSIX EREs (which include `?`). GNU awk has a couple of extensions such as `\s` for `[[:space:]]` and `\<` for word boundaries but that's all. perl on the other hand supports PCREs which are a pretty different syntax of regexps and are more different from POSIX BREs and POSIX EREs than they are from each other.

Answer (score 2):

In your awk commands and example, awk regards file.txt as having only one field because you have not defined FS, so the default whitespace field separator is used.

With that said, you can easily AND your two pattern matches together like this:

```
awk '($1 !~ /^[[:digit:]]/) && ($1 !~ /^G-[[:digit:]]/) {print $0}' file.txt
```

To make awk use comma as a field separator, you can define it in a BEGIN block.  In this example, the output should be just `line3`

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} ($1 !~ /^[[:digit:]]/) && ($1 !~ /^G-[[:digit:]]/) {print $2}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the literal translation of that grep command in awk is

```sh
awk '
  /^[[:digit:]]/ {next}
  /^G-[[:digit:]]/ {next}
  {print}
' file.txt
```

But you have several examples of how to write it more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
awk '$1 !~ /^(G-)?[[:digit:]]/' file.txt > output.txt
```

The `awk` tries to find in Field 1:

- `^` - start of string
- `(G-)?` - an optional `G-` char sequence (note the regex flavor in `awk` is POSIX ERE, so `(...)` denotes a capturing group and `?` denotes a *one or zero times* quantifier)
- `[[:digit:]]` - a digit.

If the match is found, the record (=line) is not printed. Else, the line is printed.

Answer (score 1):

to stick to your question, I would use:

```
awk '$1 !~ /^[[:digit:]]/ && $1 !~ /G-[[:digit:]]/' file.txt > output.txt
```

But I like the @Wiktor Stribiżew REGEX approach!

Comment: Regarding `\-` - you don't need to escape `-` in a regexp, it's already literal unless it's inside a bracket expression and then for portability to all awk versions you should place it as the first or last char to make it literal rather than escaping it. The script in your answer is already present in other answers that were posted before yours though.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks: fixed. My solution is similar to others already present but more concise, so I think it could be useful leave it anyway

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, this could be also done in `grep` in a single regexp, we need not to chain the different regex, adding this solution in case you/anyone need it; could be helpful.

```
grep -v -E '^(G-)?[[:digit:]]' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `grep`'s `-v` option to omit lines which are matching the mentioned pattern. Then using `-E` option of it to enable ERE(extended regular expressions). In main program using regex `^(G-)?[[:digit:]]` to match if line starts from G- OR digit then don't print that line.